# Reading integer from gridview textbox

Tags: asp.net, string, visual-studio-2010, gridview

I am converting a string that is being read from a textbox in gridview

int numTC = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)row.FindControl("numTC")).Text);

However it is returning the following exception:

Input string was not in a correct format.

Can anyone see anything wrong in the conversion?

Thanks

Comment: Please post complete code where you trying to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make Sure that your gridview can accept only numbers you can have a filterextender using ajax and I m sure u will do that what else you can do is to check whether you have a textbox is null or not using the Function given below

if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextBox)Row.FindControl("numTC")).Text))
{}

```
((TextBox)GridViewname.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("numTC")).Text;
```

and

use this extender or u can use javascript as well

If it is going inside the if statement that means the value is null

```
 if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextBox)row.FindControl("numTC")).Text)) {}
```

I have used ! sign now it will go inside the if statement if there is some value in it.
and try to convert this text into integer using try catch block if u get any exception you can take whatever action you want to.
Let me know if it is complete

Comment: youre right, its not reading anything, its going in the if statement, do you have any idea how i can correct this?

Comment: If it is going inside the if statement that means the value is null

Comment: yes yes the value is null, now im trying to find out why it is null since i am inputting values. ill get back to you

Comment: what is the standard line of code to read from a textbox in gridview? im thinking i got that wrong from the start

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious that the value of the returned in the "Text" property of the text box cannot be converted to inter, I guess you have to insure first that you are returning the correct textbox and that it contains a valid value before attempting the conversion.